# Type problem with Usize and Index in a quicksort algorithm

Tags: rust, quicksort

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm with rust, the problem is that, I have a var named '**i**' which is used as an iterator, but at first, its value is '-1', and I cannot set it to a usize type because it is negative, but I also cannot set it to a isize type because isize types cannot be used as indices.

Partition function:

```
  fn partition(arr: &mut [isize], low: usize, high: usize) -> usize {
        let mut i: usize = low - 1; // when changed to isize, I do not encounter any errors but the algorithm itself doesnt work like it should.//
        let mut j: usize = low;
        let pivot: isize = arr[high];
        while j < high {
            if arr[j] <= pivot {
                i += 1;
                arr.swap(i, j);
            }
            j += 1;
        }
        arr.swap(i + 1, high);
        return i + 1;
    }
```

if I try to run the code above with another quicksort function, this is the error I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src\functions.rs:2:24
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are of course many ways of solving this. The easiest is to let `i` start at `low` instead of `low - 1`, and increment `i` after swapping:

```
fn partition(arr: &mut [isize], low: usize, high: usize) -> usize {
    let mut i: usize = low;
    let pivot: isize = arr[high];
    for j in low..high {
        if arr[j] <= pivot {
            arr.swap(i, j);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    arr.swap(i, high);
    return i;
}
```

This way, `i` can never be less than zero, while the code still does exactly the same thing.

(Note that I also used a `for` loop to lopp over the values for `j`. This change isn't really needed, but it makes the code easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use casts to index with `isize`, since you know they never overflow. It also covers the full slice range, since [slices cannot have more than `isize::MAX` elements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#500-504):

```rust
fn partition(arr: &mut [isize], low: usize, high: usize) -> usize {
    let mut i = low as isize - 1;
    let mut j = low;
    let pivot = arr[high];
    while j < high {
        if arr[j] <= pivot {
            i += 1;
            arr.swap(i as usize, j);
        }
        j += 1;
    }
    arr.swap((i + 1) as usize, high);
    return (i + 1) as usize;
}
```

For extra safety (at the expense of performance), you can use `try_into()`:

```rust
fn partition(arr: &mut [isize], low: usize, high: usize) -> usize {
    let mut i = isize::try_from(low).unwrap() - 1;
    let mut j = low;
    let pivot = arr[high];
    while j < high {
        if arr[j] <= pivot {
            i += 1;
            arr.swap(i.try_into().unwrap(), j);
        }
        j += 1;
    }
    arr.swap((i + 1).try_into().unwrap(), high);
    return (i + 1).try_into().unwrap();
}
```

But I would not recommend walking this path, but rather, changing your code to use `usize` as noted in the answer by @SvenMarnach.